# How do I include a font file (.ttf) in my Android NDK project?

Tags: android, android-ndk, freetype, freetype2

So I need to include a .ttf font file for Freetype font rendering in my Android NDK project. Where do I put it so that it will be put in the apk?

Comment: The typical approach is to put it in `assets/`. I don't know much about how you will use it, but my guess is that you will need to copy the asset (from `AssetManager`) to a local file on the filesystem, then have your native code use that local filesystem copy.

Comment: Assets worked. Want to post as answer?

Comment: I would recommend that you post the answer, as you can explain how you are using that asset with respect to the NDK.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `src/main/` I created another folder `assets/` alongside the `java/`, `jni/`, and `res/` folders where I placed the `.ttf` file and it was uploaded to the apk. I'm still trying to get Freetype to see it as the current command isn't getting it:

```
FT_New_Face(ft, "/assets/Arial.ttf", 0, &face);
```

But that's another question.

Comment: Why marked as answered? Any news on that front? I encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I will add my solution, it's by passing the assetManager, and keep a reference to it in the c++ side. The font ttf file is stored in the assets folder inside a fonts folder.

```
FT_library library;
FT_Face fontFace;

AAsset* fontFile = AAssetManager_open(manager, "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf", AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
off_t fontDataSize = AAsset_getLength(fontFile);

FT_Byte* fontData = new FT_Byte[fontDataSize];
AAsset_read(fontFile, fontData, (size_t) fontDataSize);
AAsset_close(fontFile);


if (FT_Init_FreeType(&library)) {
    LOGE("Could not load library");
}
if (FT_New_Memory_Face(library, (const FT_Byte*)fontData, (FT_Long)fontDataSize, 0, &fontFace)) {
    LOGE("Load memory failed");
}
```

To pass the assetManager just pass it as an object and convert on the C++ side.

```
AAssetManager *manager = AAssetManager_fromJava(javaEnv, assetObject);
```

Comment: I will add that this is for loading custom fonts, for system fonts this is not needed since you access directly without the AssetManager.